# Can't use TS/JS decorators with jsbundling/esbuild on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, typescript, esbuild, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to get Angular to run in a Rails 6 project. I have installed the jsbundling-rails (with esbuild) and typescript-rails gems to load my JavaScript and TypeScript files. What should happen is that I write some TS, then typescript-rails transpiles it to JS, then esbuild bundles it all up and jsbundling-rails runs it on the Rails application.

This sort of works, but not when I use a TypeScript decorator like `@NgModule`. It gets transpiled to JS alright, but then it doesn't run because I get an `Invalid or unexpected token` error at the @ sign. I tried putting the `--experimentalDecorators` flag in the typescript-rails config, but it did not help.

Is this happening because the typescript-rails gem is turning (standard) TS decorators into (unsupported) JS decorators? Should I get rid of typescript-rails (I couldn't get the TS to run until I installed it)? Can I make the JS compiler support decorators?

Comment: `typescript-rails` has not been updated in 7 years. `jsbundling-rails` can handle typescript with esbuild. See this issue regarding decorators: https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/104

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah I ended up ditching typescript-rails and getting esbuild to handle it. So that's alright. Now I'm trying to get the module import paths to work. Sigh.